# Trigger (Networktest) installation on Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess

Currently I have the problem that I get the following error message under Python 3.7 when installing the package trigger (network test for router / switch).

If you try to install the offending package separately, then you get the same error message.

```
Collecting gtextfsm (from trigger)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/12/edfdccf3d968ffbb94ac8e48b3172395b6902eb4265bded0b0d07a1652f3/gtextfsm-0.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4_suoa4z\gtextfsm\setup.py", line 19, in <module>
        import textfsm
      File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4_suoa4z\gtextfsm\textfsm\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        __version__ = textfsm.__version__
    NameError: name 'textfsm' is not defined-
```

Is there another alternative to triggers?

Did someone have the problem described above?

Other solutions?

Comment: same here, any idea?